# Azure Function - Blob Trigger for Encrypted Blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, .net-6.0

We are storing encrypted blobs in blob container using one of our endpoints (web api).
Encryption is done using CustomerProvidedKey of BlobClientOptions() in Azure.Storage.Blobs package.

We are thinking to add **blob trigger** azure function so that we can process the blobs as soon as they are added in the container.

```
[FunctionName("BlobsProcessor")]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("abc/{name}", Connection = "Connection")] Stream stream, string name)
```

However, we are receiving below error:

```
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.838Z] Azure.Storage.Blobs: Service request failed.
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.839Z] Status: 409 (The blob is encrypted with customer specified encryption, but it was not provided in the request.)
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.839Z] ErrorCode: BlobUsesCustomerSpecifiedEncryption
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.841Z]
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.841Z] Headers:
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.842Z] Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.843Z] Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.844Z] x-ms-request-id: 3a26939d-301e-0043-3643-5c2c33000000
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.844Z] x-ms-client-request-id: 70530a07-4218-480b-b996-efbcfd118691
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.845Z] x-ms-version: 2021-12-02
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.845Z] x-ms-error-code: BlobUsesCustomerSpecifiedEncryption
[2023-03-21T22:24:05.846Z] Date: Tue, 21 Mar 2023 22:24:04 GMT
```

Please Note:
We tried replacing stream with string/byte[] but everything ended up with same error.
We are looking for real time blob processing. Any pointers to proceed or resolve this issue or any workaround would be great?